# Why is Internet Explorer used without my intervention?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer

I don't use Internet Explorer.  Yet, since I installed ccleaner, I noticed that some Internet Explorer cookies are set (I noticed that when I ccleaner informed me that some temporary files could be deleted).

What can be the origin of these cookes?

For example, here is the content of two recent such cookies:

_DetectCookiesYoffice.microsoft.com/102....*
_DetectCookiesYofficeimg.vo.msecnd.net/1024....*

Comment: The cookie is connected to Office.  What version of Office do you have installed?

Comment: I have Office 2010

Comment: `Office 2010` has an online `Help` feature.  This `Help` feature uses the Trident/IE engine.  I would say its safe to say your cookies are from that feature.

Comment: Ok... but I never used the help feature: just straight editing a word document - and looking at a spreadsheet.  But given the cookie name, it seems like the most likely answer.  You may want to change your first comment as an answer so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: I am not going to post that as an answer.  Your welcome to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that automates Internet Explorer to show web content, potentially. In other words as a COM object. Our own desktop ERP product that we develop uses InternetExplorer.Application as the application background to display news and the like.

Comment: I don't use anything like this (as far as I know). However, I do use MS Office.